# Expire signature

Tags: signature, algorithm-design, timestamping

I am looking for a way to have a 'did it expired' key.

There's a similar question [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2497/digital-signature-for-an-expiring-password), but I have to prevent reusing of the 'did it expired' signature .

A possible solution would be a two one-way functions f,g such that-

- Faythe generate `key=f(private key,some date)` and send it to Alice.
- Alice send `g(key,hash(message))` to Bob.
- Bob can verify that the message is up to date with the public key.

I thought of doing this with the Yao's Millionaires' Problem saying Alice has a signed value which only Bob can decrypt, but couldn't figure how to extend it.

Can Someone help me find  f,g or perhaps a better idea?

Comment: Since you don't seem to rule out having a trusted third party involved, is there any other reason why you can't use standard signature algorithms, X.509 certificates and PKCS#7 with external time stamping by the trusted third party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to rely on identity-based signatures.

A trusted third party (TTP) defines a set of RSA keys $\mathit{mpk} = \{N,e\}$ and $\mathit{msk} = \{p,q,d\}$ where $N = pq$ for two large primes $p,q$ and $e,d$ such that $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod {(p-1)(q-1)}$. Key $\mathit{mpk}$ is public and is used to check the correctness of signatures; key $\mathit{msk}$ is secret and is used by the TTP to generate signing keys for a given time period.  Let also $H$ be a cryptographic hash function.

If Alice wishes to obtain a signing key valid up to, say, May 30, 2016, the TTP computes the signing $\mathit{sk}_A = [H(Alice\|05302016)]^d \bmod N$ and gives it to Alice.

Alice can now sign a message $M$ using $\mathit{sk}_A$ as

1. choose a random $t \in \mathbb{Z}_N$;
2. compute $T = t^e \bmod N$, $c = H(T\|M)$, $s = \mathit{sk}_A \cdot t^c \bmod N$;
3. return the signature $\sigma=(T,s)$.

Anyone can check that $\sigma=(T,s)$ is Alice's signature on message $M$ with expiry date $05/30/2016$ using the verification key $\mathit{mpk}$ by checking that $s^e \equiv H(Alice\|05302016) \cdot T^{H(T\|M)} \pmod N$.

Comment: Whats Alice under the hash stands for?Her pub key?

Comment: Great! By the way in you're implementation we can say Faythe is the TTP CA.

Comment: @Shoham Baris: In identity-based signature schemes, the identity plays the role of the public key.  So, if you wish, *Alice* may be seen as Alice's public key.  For your second question, Faythe can be the TTP.